# Spacing between histogram bars with thousands of bins

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, histogram, width

I'm making histograms using matplotlib's `hist()` function or `bar()`, and I want to use >10,000 bins (one bin to represent the counts at each coordinate of a large entity). Is there any way to create more whitespace between the vertical bars when I create the figure? Currently, there is no whitespace between each bar of the histogram. For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# Generating dummy data    
coordinate_counts = [random.randrange(1,10000) for __ in range(1,100000)]

# plotting
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.hist(coordinate_counts, bins=range(1,10000))
```

I've tried using `rwidth` and varying the value of that, as well as tried using `figsize` and simply expanding the size of the plot, but the final result always has each vertical bar next to each other with no whitespace in-between.

Comment: I think you might be expecting too much from your display - how do you expect to see space between each of 10000 bins (or even to see all 10000 un-downsampled bins) when your monitor probably only has ~2000 ish pixels across it?

Answer (score 55):

The parameter `rwidth` specifies the width of your bar relative to the width of your bin. For example, if your `bin` width is say 1 and `rwidth=0.5`, the bar width will be **0.5**. On both side of the bar you will have a space of **0.25**.

Mind: this gives a space of 0.5 between consecutive bars. With the number of bins you have, you won't see these spaces. But with fewer bins they do show up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`plt.hist` ultimately uses `plt.bar` plot the bars so another way to make a gap between bars is through `width=` parameter.

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.hist(coordinate_counts, bins=range(1, 10000), width=0.5)
```

One thing to note is that unlike `rwidth` where the width of a bar depends on how large its bin is (and is a value between 0 and 1), `width` is an absolute value that determines how wide the bar should be (and can be larger than 1). An example may illustrate better. The following code

```py
coordinate_counts = list(range(10))*10
plt.hist(coordinate_counts, bins=[0, 3, 8, 10], width=2);
```

plots the following chart

[image: first histogram]

while the following code plots

```py
plt.hist(coordinate_counts, bins=[0, 3, 8, 10], rwidth=0.5);
```

[image: second hist]