# How to manually set the width of the bars in pyplot histogram, without changing the bin size or number

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Is there a possibility in matplotlib.pyplot to have a histogram, where bar width is not identical to bin size? For example, if `bar_width>bin_size`, the bars should overlap on graph and if `bar_width<bin_size`, the bars will have gaps in between.
Additionally: I would like to set up the width manually, not relative to bin size (I'm plotting big number of histograms with different bin sizes, but I want to unify their look).

Comment: [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31047434/8881141) different [approaches.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58186329/8881141)

Comment: You can also add an edgecolor (of 'white' for example) and line thickness.

Comment: Thanks, the second option is what I'm looking for, although it quite of a workaround!